# c++ class constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have code which go like this

```
class A_
 {
  public:
  int k;

  A_(int a):k(a)
  {cout<<"A_'s constructor called"<<endl;  
    }

  virtual   ~A_()
   {
    cout<<"class A_ destructor"<<endl;
    }
 virtual void getval() { cout<<k<<endl;}

};

class A : public A_
 {
  public:
  int m;
  A(int a):A_(2),m(a){cout<<"A's constructor called"<<endl;}
  virtual void getval()
   {
    cout<<"m is "<<m<<endl;
    }
   ~A()
    {
     cout<<"class A destructor"<<endl;
     }
};
int main()
{
  A A1(1);
  A_(2);
  cin.get();
  }
```

When I run this code I get result which goes like this(program reached till `cin.get()`)

`A_'s constructor called`

`A's constructor called`

`A_'s constructor called`

`class A_ destructor`

I was expecting the A_ object created within class A to be destroyed immediately like in the case when  `A_(2)` in `main ()` is executed, but it is not happening here. The `A_` object is destroyed only when program reaches end(after entering some text as input)

`class A destructor`

`class A_ destructor`

Question:

1) Why was object of `A_` class created along with `A` object not destroyed immediately?

2) Is there any circumstance when an object of base class calls a method of derived class? In particular is is possible for an `A_` object to call `getval()` of `A`object?

Comment: Do you know what inheritance is and how it works? To answer your second question - yes, that's what polymorphism is based upon.

Comment: @littleadv You are right, my understanding of inheritance was not complete, I was thinking an object of base class is created in the derived class object, it didn't occur to me that base class constructor is required to initialize data members derived form base class. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has three different reasons.

1. Destructors are called in a FILO/stack order (first in last out).
2. Scope comes into play. In your instance, the only scope is the main function
3. Inheritance. A inherits from A_.

If you think about it, in order for an object of type "A" to be created, it has to first know what to inherit from "A_". Therefore, A_ is created first, then A. Then of course, your line "A_(2)" is run, resulting in the second call to the A_ constructor.

Then, because the scope has ended, the destructor is called in reverse order. A_(2) is destroyed, then A(1), then the A_ that A(1) inherited from.